# Get Json values from string

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json string like the below format. I would like to get the Table1.ActualDate value. How can i get this using jquery.

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "DisplayVoucherNumber": "A101239Z",
            "ActualDate": "08/07/2013",
            "AccountName": "shyamal",
            "Pcs": "50",
            "Weight": "500.000"
        }
    ],
    "Table1": [
        {
            "DisplayVoucherNumber": "R101249B",
            "ActualDate": "11/07/2013",
            "AccountName": "vipul",
            "NetWeight": "90.000",
            "Weight": "80.000",
            "Difference": "10.000"
        },
        {
            "DisplayVoucherNumber": "R101249B",
            "ActualDate": "11/07/2013",
            "AccountName": "vipul",
            "NetWeight": "500.000",
            "Weight": "100.000",
            "Difference": "400.000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: there are 2 `ActualDate ` values... which one

Comment: if `data` refers to this object then `data.Table1[0].ActualDate`..

Comment: and `data.Table1[1].ActualDate`

Comment: var jObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);for(i=0;i<jObj.Table1.length;i++) {
console.log(jObj.Table1[i].ActualDate); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `parse` that string to get a valid `JSON` object.

Try,

```
var xObj = JSON.parse(xString);
console.log(xObj.Table1[0].ActualDate);
```

where `xString` is the `string` variable contains your `JSON` string.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string, you should make it as a json object using

```
var data= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

After that can use it like.

```
 alert(data.Table1[0].ActualDate);
```

If it is an abject already, you dont have to use the `jQuery.parseJSON()` method

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Table1` array may grow, I would suggest you to go for iteration like

```
var tab = JSON.parse("you object");
for (i = 0; i < tab["Table1"].length; i++) {
    console.log(tab["Table1"][i].AccountName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jObj = JSON.parse(jsonString); // Converts the string to JSON object

if(jObj !== undefined && jObj.Table1 !== undefined) {
    for (i = 0; i < jObj.Table1.length; i++) {
        console.log(jObj.Table1[i].ActualDate); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$.each(json.Table1, function(x, contents) {
    alert(contents.ActualDate);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BgLHc/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
        var json = {
            "Table": [
                {
                    "DisplayVoucherNumber": "A101239Z",
                    "ActualDate": "08/07/2013",
                    "AccountName": "shyamal",
                    "Pcs": "50",
                    "Weight": "500.000"
                }
            ],
            "Table1": [
                {
                    "DisplayVoucherNumber": "R101249B",
                    "ActualDate": "11/07/2013",
                    "AccountName": "vipul",
                    "NetWeight": "90.000",
                    "Weight": "80.000",
                    "Difference": "10.000"
                },
                {
                    "DisplayVoucherNumber": "R101249B",
                    "ActualDate": "13/08/2012",
                    "AccountName": "vipul",
                    "NetWeight": "500.000",
                    "Weight": "100.000",
                    "Difference": "400.000"
                }
            ]
        };


        for(var i=0; i<json.Table1.length; ++i) {
            alert(json.Table1[i].ActualDate)
        }
```